# What are alternatives to Miro Software?

Tags: 20.04, software-recommendation, diagram

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 (kde) and I need a diagram creator software like Miro https://miro.com/login/ .
I have already found some alternatives like Dia, LibreOffice Draw, Calligra Flow but they are not so handy. I would like to install a software that can allows me to export diagrams in eps/svg/pdf formats, and use various pre-defined templates.

I usually use inkscape for drawing diagrams. Do you know if I can import shapes in inkscape like in the Miro software ?
Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem and can guarantee you will LOVE Google drawings https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1CwsTB23Lh2F9dsGGRqZ4Uprq0CuJeVClrX1KES4TumM/edit

Comment: I'm curious what you meant by "not so catchy"...  For drawing diagrams, flowcharts, etc., I now use `dia` and I personally think it's great...  I'm open to better software, but preferred `dia` over `inkscape`.  Inkscape has a lot more features...more than what I needed.